# Detect and Manipulate Fonts Used in XPS Documents with C#

Tags: c#, fonts, replace, find, xps

I am looking to develop/locate a find-replace tool for XPS documents.

Does anyone know how to detect the the fonts used within XPS Documents within C#? And also how to produce an ODTTF Fils based on TypeFace Characters/Font?

Kind regards,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the first 32 bytes of the ODTTF to determine its name once you're in XPS package (System.IO.Packaging).